# Why do I have to send the content type data in the header so that the result is correct?

Tags: java, webclient, spring-webflux

I have a problem when I try to make a request with webclient.

the server only supports
Content-Type: application / json; charset = UTF-8

This is my webclient configuration, but I always get the error:
415 Unsupported Media Type

```
 LinkedMultiValueMap mapBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap();

 List<String> ingredientsList = new ArrayList<String>();
 ingredientsList.add("200g Lentejas 20g chorizo");

 mapBody.add("title", "lentejas con chorizo");
 mapBody.add("ingr", ingredientsList);

BodyInserters.MultipartInserter inserterBody = BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(mapBody);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(this.api_nutrition_uri);

        Mono<NutritionResModel> response = webClient
                .post()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/api/nutrition-details")
                        .queryParam("app_id", api_nutrition_appId)
                        .queryParam("app_key", api_nutrition_appKey)
                        .build())
                //.headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                //.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(inserterBody)
                //.header("Content-Type", "application/json")

                .retrieve()
                //.doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> System.out.println("clientResponse.statusCode() = " + clientResponse.headers()))
                //.doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> System.out.println("clientResponse.statusCode() = " + clientResponse.statusCode()))
                //.flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(NutritionResModel.class));
                .bodyToMono(NutritionResModel.class);
```

I don't know how I have to send the content type data in the header so that the result is correct

thanks!!!

Comment: Were you able to call the API manually (for example via Postman) successfully? Is it possible that the issue is on the API side instead of the client side?

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I found the error in this line:
 .body (inserterBody)

I have changed it to this other line:
.body (BodyInserters.fromObject (nutritionReqModel))

// nutritionReqModel is a java bean with @jsonProperty

I think the problem was that the data I added in the body in the "inserterBody" object didn't detect it as an object transformed into json

Comment: you can instead of using a dedicated body inserter you can just use `syncBody(nutritionReqModel)`